# invalid expression: invalid regular expression flag p in image

Tags: regex, laravel, vue.js

I get this error:

```
Error compiling template: invalid expression: invalid regular expression flag p in /uploads/product/1560228180.png Raw expression: :src="/uploads/product/1560228180.png"



<!-- MENAMPILKAN IMAGE DARI PRODUCT --> 62 | <div class="col-md-3" v-if="product.photo"> 63 | <img :src="/uploads/product/1560228180.png" :alt="product.title" width="150px" height="150px"> | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 64 | </div> 65 | </div>
```

my js cant compile template and give me this error message:

```
 Error compiling template: invalid expression: invalid regular expression flag p in /uploads/product/1560228180.png Raw expression: :src="/uploads/product/1560228180.png"



<!-- MENAMPILKAN IMAGE DARI PRODUCT --> 62 | <div class="col-md-3" v-if="product.photo"> 63 | <img :src="/uploads/product/1560228180.png" :alt="product.title" width="150px" height="150px"> | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 64 | </div> 65 | </div>
```

Comment: try with `src` instead of `:src` since it's not a javascript expression

Comment: Or put quotes inside v-bind to make it a string. `:src="'/uploads/product/1560228180.png'"`